# Hotkey to block highlight text in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, text

Does this exist in VS?

Is there a way you can manually map it in: Tools -> Options -> Keyboard?

I want to block highlight without having to hit the arrow key to expand a highlighted area.

I'm using C#, WPF, XAML if that's relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by "block highlight text?"

Comment: a block is a chunk of code, usually beginning and ending with brackets. I'd like to be able to highlight a block of text with a a key combination.

Comment: Ah, ok. The only thing I know of is holding down the Shift key and then using the Arrow keys.

Comment: VS already has this built-in for C# beginning/ending brackets.  For example, put your cursor before/after the opening bracket of a C# method, then press Shift+Ctrl+].  It will select the entire contents between the curly { and } brackets (including the brackets).  Now put the cursor on the closing bracket and press Shift+Ctrl+].  It will do the same thing.

Comment: This is close enough to what I was looking for, thank you.

It would be cool if you could do the same thing so that it would include the method/class definition though.